# reading data from files and store them in vector<vector<pair<int,int>>> in c++

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, data-structures, stl

I have a file say `data.txt` in which data is as like below;

```
1   80,982 163,8164
2   42,1689 127,9365 5,8026
3   57,1239 101,3381 43,731 115,7827 17,7002 72,794 150,4539
4   162,3924 70,5285 195,2490 72,6508 126,2625 121,7639 31,399 118,3626 90,9446 127,6808
```

i have a container as  `vector<vector<pair<int,int>>>Graph(100)`,
by reading above data I want to perform operation as `Graph[1].push_back({80,982})` , `Graph[1].push_back({163,864})`.

similarly `Graph[2].push_back({42,1689})`, `Graph[2].push_back({127,9365})`, `Graph[2].push_back({5,8026})`.
and so on for the third row, till it gets end. I have little idea I can use `ifstream file("data.txt");` and then taking a string variable `string str` and proceed in this way.

```
 while (getline(file, str)) {
        //perform operation
        // stringstream ss(str) can be used to parse commas
        //how to deal with variable length.
    }
```

please help me how can I do the above task. thank you so much.

Comment: You have two problems. The first is parsing numbers separated by commas. The second is reading lines of variable length. Have you attempted either of these before?

Comment: I know parsing the numbers separated by any delimiter, but looking for help with the variable length.

Answer (score 0):

To read lines of variable length, you must read the whole line at once, *then* parse it.

To read the whole line, use `getline`:

```
string str;
getline(cin, str);
```

(This is one of several variants of `getline`.)

Then to parse it, you could iterate over it, looking for spaces and commas, and converting numerals into numbers, but that is very tedious. C++ allows the use of `stringstream`, which is easier:

```
#include <sstream>

std::stringstream ss;
ss << str;

int n=0;
string word;
while(ss >> word)
  cout << ++n << " " << word << endl;
```